# How to force the restart of a python script

Tags: python, multithreading

Im using threads and queues to request exchange data from their APIs, here's an exert of one exchange (there are several of these)

```
queueS = Queue.Queue()
q = threading.Thread(target=getData, args=(queueS,))
q.start()
```

I'm running the script on a `while True` loop. However one exchange throws an error every hour or so and the script freezes

I have `try:  except: pass` around everything, I can't figure out why the script doesn't skip it when it throws an error.

One way to fix it would be to forceably restart the script every time. What do you guys think ?

EDIT: the getData function shows that the error is coming from the exchange when the API is called:

```
def getData(queue,exchange):
    try:
        data = requests.get(urls[exchange]).json()
        queue.put(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print exchange, e
        pass
```

It then just stalls after this and doesn't continue. I suspect it could be something to do with the multithreading.

Comment: If you do `except Exception as e: log.error(e)` you might be able to log the root cause.

Comment: Hi, thank for the reply. So I actually did this and the problem is with the exchange throwing an error. It just stalls after though

Comment: That's good. At least it eliminated a bunch of possibility

Comment: This `getData` puts data into the queue. Can you show the code that pops data from the queue?